# Use wildcard (or regexp) in HTMLparser HasAttributeFilter parameter

Tags: java, html-parsing, html-parser

I use org.htmlparser. How I can received nodelist by class mask?
On example:

```
<span class="selection-link normal coeff816128@Result.draw">....</span>
<span class="selection normal coefd816154@Result.draw">....</span>
```

and I want to receive all tags which has "normal" as class.
Unfortunately

> new HasAttributeFilter("class", "normal")

do not work.
Is HTMLparser allowed something like `new HasAttributeFilter("class", "\*normal*")`?

Answer (score 0):

If you possible you can try [jsoup](http://www.jsoup.org) - its a very capable opensource html library.

Here's an example how to get (and print) each element with *normal* as class:

**Input Html:**

```
<span class="selection-link normal coeff816128@Result.draw">....</span>
<span class="selection-link coeff816128@Result.draw">....</span>
<span class="selection coefd816154@Result.draw">....</span>
<span class="selection normal coefd816154@Result.draw">....</span>
```

*(it's yours, but with two extra `span`'s which dont have a `normal` class)*

**Jsoup:**

```
/* Input file - containing the html listed above.*/
final File f = new File("test.html");

/*
 * Parse the html into a jsoup document. In this example i get it from
 * the file, but its possible to parse from string or connect to a
 * website.
 */
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(f, null);


/* Iterate over eacht element */
for( Element element : doc.select("*.normal") )
{
    System.out.println(element);
}
```

With `*.normal` you select every element with class `normal`. however, if you only wont those with `span` tag use `span.normal` instead.

For documentation of the Jsoup selector api see here: http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax

btw. if you want to use DOM selectors instead of `select()`: `doc.getElementsByClass("normal")`